# Find element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to find **class="a-icon a-icon-addon couponBadge"** on Amazon page, like [this](https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07WJGLGR7).
If the class exist, i need to set variable x == 0, if it doesn't exist, i need to set variable x == 1.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. How can i check this?

```
try:
    couponBadge = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-icon a-icon-addon couponBadge")
    if couponBadge != None:
        x == 0
    else:
        x == 1
except AttributeError:
    print("error")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a single equals sign, not two, to assign to a variable.

e.g. `x = 1`

It also looks like Selenium's `get_elements_by_class_name` function only supports inputting a single class name, not multiple as is shown in your example, so you might want to look into [`driver.find_element_by_css_selector()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors).

e.g. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-icon.a-icon-addon.couponBadge')`

Answer (score 4):

Please try this:

```
couponBadge = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-icon a-icon-addon couponBadge")
if couponBadge:
    x = 0
else:
    x = 1
```

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name` returns a list.
In case there are elements matching this locator the list will be non-empty, so it will be interpreted as a Boolean True. Otherwise it will be interpreted as False.
Also to assign a value to variable you should use a single `=`, not `==`.
`==` is used for comparison.
Also, as mentioned by CrunchyBox you should rather use `find_element_by_css_selector`, not `get_elements_by_class_name`.